# CD/DVD burner D: not showing up on file explorer

Tags: windows-10

CD/DVD disk drive does not show up on file explorer.
If I put in a SW disk it shows up and I can read it but if i put in a blank disk it does not show up and D: is not shown on the drive list.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 provides an option to hide empty drives. Perhaps this applies to blank discs.

1. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+10+hide+empty+drive
2. http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/14/windows-10/hide-empty-removable-disk-drives-windows-10.html
3. Launch Windows Explorer
4. In the Ribbon Menu: Click on the View tab
5. Click the Options button to bring up the Folder Options dialog box.
6. Click on the View tab,
7. In Advanced settings subsection, un-click the checkbox against the Hide empty drives option.
8. Click Apply,

Comment: Thank You. This helped me fix it.  I had to unhide it and I had to go to Navigation Pane and "Show all folders". If it is hidden my burner can't find it.  Now it shows up.